# What causes LG screen colors to change when I install a Mac OS update?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro

I have 2 Macbook Pro 15 inch from 2018.

I have updated one of the both with the last Mac OS update (not exactly the last but 1 before), and my 2 LG external screens (4k) are not usable anymore, it burst my eyes, especially on heat colors (i barely don't see any difference on dark colors, but for example, white on green really hurts your eyes).

Since i have the chance to have 2 identical Macbook Pro and i didn't update the second one, i made the test to plug it instead of the updated one (i am using 2 USB C port). And it still works fine!

It's been almost 2 years i have these Macbook Pro and these 2 screens, everything always worked perfectly, and the issue appeared right after the update on one of it.

What do you think i should do ?

Comment: Check they're both using the same profile - System Prefs/Displays/Colour.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've the same issue.. Working on a 15 inch macbook (2018) and just update to macOS Catalina 10.15.4. Macbook itself working fine but my LG 27UK850 monitor isn't showing matching colours anymore.. Tried a restart of my macbook but that didn't help. Monitor to factory settings isn't fixing anything as well.. Macbook colour repair shows me that I've around 30 bad colour profiles. Don't know if this is what has to be fixed but i can't repair it unfortunately..

If your color changes as the sun comes up and down, [check for Night Shift](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/change-displays-night-shift-preferences-mchl9d976e85/mac).

**I've found how to fix it.**

1. Go to System Preferences
2. Go to Displays
3. Turn off 'High Dynamic Range' This fixed it for me. Hopefully for you as well =)

If this doesn’t fix it, consider performing a full calibration for both machines and check other settings relating to color.

- https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/calibrate-your-display-mchlp1109/mac
- https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/change-your-displays-color-profile-mchlf3ddc60d/mac
- https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/if-your-display-doesnt-look-right-mchlp2906/mac

Comment: Interesting. How do you initiate a MacBook color repair?

Comment: I've found how to fix it. 

1. Go to System Preferences

2. Go to Displays

3. Turn off 'High Dynamic Range'

This fixed it for me. Hopefully for you as well =)

Comment: Add that to the body of the answer! Will help others spot the solution.

Comment: @bmike on my macbook you have to go to launchpad > ColorSync Utility. Here you can run a test which shows you all the colour profiles

Comment: ColorSync Utility is in Applications/Utilities, for those who don't use the Launchpad.

Comment: I thought i would never be able to get it back, thanks a lot !

Comment: Lifesaver! Thanks a lot!